# Error Loging with variable names and values that was used in method

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

Is there any way, to log all variables and the values that were used in the method?
I want to see log information like I showed in the method `ErrorWriter`. I don't want to use something like `ErrorWriter(names, values)`. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
    static int number3;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        number3 = 0;
        Method(1, 2);
    }
    static void Method(int number, int number2)
    {
        int number4;
        try
        {
            number4 = number / number2 / number3;
        }
        catch
        {
            ErrorWriter();
        }
    }

    private static void ErroWriter()
    {
        /// number = 1
        /// number2 = 2
        /// number3 = 0
    }
```

I need information about variable values which was used. For example. If i have a line number4=number/number2/number3 . How can i know which variable value was 0? Number 2 or number 3? That's why i need exact values. I don't want to hardcode parameter for every different method. I need dynamic solution.

Comment: What about writing exception message and stacktrace? Why do your need numbers?

Comment: I need information about variable values which was used. For example. If i have a line number4=number/number2/number3 . And i have only stacktrace. How can i know which was 0? Number 2 or number 3? That's why i need exact values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of aspect programming/interception for this. Any other approach you take will probably end up being to low level or complicated for something that shouldn't be on the actual class you are implementing.

Error Handling is not necessarily one of the responsabilities of your class so it can be delegated to an aspect.

One possible solution would be to use some kind of [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) framework (like [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx) and [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), there are many others) and set up your classes to be intercepted by an error handling interceptor, which will catch exceptions and log the parameters in those cases.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx) has an example using Unity that can point you to the right solution

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, using standard error handling routines would probably serve you much better than what you're trying to accomplish here.

Anyway, your `ErrorWriter` method could take a parameter of type `int[]`.

```
chatch
{
    ErrorWriter(new int[3] { number1, number2, number3 });
}

(...)

private static void ErrorWriter(int[] numbers)
{
    int index = 1;
    foreach(var i in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("number" + index.ToString() + " = " + i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you would want to avoid the try/catch in this case.

Check in Method if your input is valid (ie. number, number 2 and number 3). Throw exception if validation fails.

If all you want is to be able to determine if one of the variables is zero (or has failed validation), throw the Exception in a check like follows:

```
private void Method(int number, int number2) {
   if (number3 == 0) throw new Exception("number3 is zero, resulting in division by zero");
   if (number2 + number == 0) throw new Exception("number2 + number is zero");
   number 4 = (number2 + number) / number3
}
```

No try/catch needed. The exception will bubble up. 
Always check your input (instance variables and parameters) before using in any method!